# Is there way to pass in object into CmisExtensionElement?

Tags: apache, alfresco, opencmis, cmis-workbench

I have a custom aspect, and I'm trying to update it's property through OpenCMIS with CmisExtensionElement.

Currently, I'm able to update custom properties having type String with following codes:

```
CmisExtensionElement extension = new CmisExtensionElementImpl(namespace, "value", null, String-value);
```

Question is, how will I able to update custom aspect having property with type datetime, as I'm not able to pass in other than string? (If I convert date object into a string, and pass it on, it throws an error...)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this : https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/properties/

You should probably use something like :

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

properties.put("my:dateVar1", new GregorianCalendar());
// OR
properties.put("my:dateVar2", new Date());
// update
cmisObject.updateProperties(properties);
```

Comment: Thanks Younes for the idea. I've actually tried that already :) That seemed to work well for non-custom aspect. It seems I must be able to leverage CmisExtensionElement...

Comment: @jkim : well according to the link, that would be the way to go for custom aspects as well... I do not believe you should be coding the way you are now TBH

Comment: Yeah, I guess it may be the case for higher version of Alfresco. I'm using Alfresco 4.2 with 0.14.0 OpenCMIS which doesn't allow user to do that, and CMISExtensionImplement is recommended, according to other sites like http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.impl.dataobjects.CmisExtensionElementImpl

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code provided by Jeff Potts that shows how to do it: https://gist.github.com/jpotts/6136702

Comment: Thanks Ben. Would you mind validating the link, as I'm not able to access it for some reason...

Comment: Ah, now it works. Well, it seems its for aspect-defined properties, similar to other answer posted. But I appreciate for the response!